# Variables across PowerPoint slides

Tags: vba, module, powerpoint

How can I make a variable accessible across slides in PowerPoint 2007? I tried:

```
Slide42.myvar = 1
```

Is there any way to declare a "global" variable that can be accessed from all slides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your variable across all slides, you need to declare it as `Public` or `Global`. You add a module to your slide and declare it as:

```
Public MyVar as Integer
```

To add a module to your slide, In the VBA editor, make sure that your presentation is highlighted in the left-hand pane. Then, choose Insert, Module from the menu bar to insert a new code module into your project. You can have your variable declarations there.